# Присвоить переменной js значение из ячейки таблицы HTML при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, table

Есть генерируемая по скрипту таблица, в которой есть порядковый номер (${num++}), данные из массива 1 и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку мне необходимо, чтобы в переменную (например x) сохранялось значение ячейки с номером строки, в которой находится сама кнопка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так я строю таблицу:

```
var num = 0;
document.querySelector('.my_deck').innerHTML = '<table class="my_cards"</table>';
var row1 = document.createElement('tr');
row1.innerHTML = '<td>Number</td><td>Class</td><td>Attak</td><td>Attak type</td><td>Accuracy</td><td>Health</td><td>Defence</td><td>Speed</td><td>Dexterity</td><td>Change card</td>';
document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row1);

DECK_PL.forEach(c => {
var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `<td>${num++}</td><td>${c.suits}</td><td>${c.attak}</td><td>${c.attaktipe}</td><td>${c.accuracy}</td><td>${c.health}</td><td>${c.defence}</td><td>${c.speed}</td><td>${c.dexterity}</td><td><button onclick="ChangeCards()">Change card</button></td>`;
document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: Минимально воспроизводимый пример [кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так я решил эту проблему:

```
function BackMyDeck(index_X, index_Y) {
  var num = 0; // порядковый номер в таблице
  var numb = 0; // данная переменная генерирует число, которое будет определять строку в таблице, которую нужно заменить
  // гнерация шапки таблицы
  document.querySelector('.my_deck').innerHTML = '<table class="my_cards"></table><button onclick="DeleteMyDeck()"> DELETE </button><button onclick="SaveMyDeck(DECK_PL, SAVEDECK)"> SAVE DECK </button>';
  var row1 = document.createElement('tr');
  row1.innerHTML = '<td>Number</td><td>Class</td><td>Attak</td><td>Attak type</td><td>Accuracy</td><td>Health</td><td>Defence</td><td>Speed</td><td>Dexterity</td><td>Change card</td>';
  document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row1);

  // генерация тела таблицы
DECK_PL.forEach(c => {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = `<td>${num++}</td><td>${c.suits}</td><td>${c.attak}</td><td>${c.attaktipe}</td><td>${c.accuracy}</td><td>${c.health}</td><td>${c.defence}</td><td>${c.speed}</td><td>${c.dexterity}</td><td><button onclick='ChangeCards(${numb++})'>Change card</button></td>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row);
  });
};
```

Теоретически это можно сделать без ввода дополнительной переменной, однако у меня не получилось заставить алгоритм работать корректно всего с одной переменной (Думаю, здесь главная причина в том, что мне просто не хватает опыта).

Answer (score 1):

Формируйте строку с датой `class=${i}` внутри неё, будет легко выяснить

```
DECK_PL.forEach(c => {
var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `<td class='td-${num++}'>${num}</td><td>${c.suits}</td><td>${c.attak}</td><td>${c.attaktipe}</td><td>${c.accuracy}</td><td>${c.health}</td><td>${c.defence}</td><td>${c.speed}</td><td>${c.dexterity}</td><td><button onclick="ChangeCards()">Change card</button></td>`;
document.querySelector('.my_cards').appendChild(row);
});
```

Затем по клику выясняете родителя клетки (строку) и считываете у него класс. Справитесь с этой частью?

---

Дополнение: способ совсем в лоб. Вовнутрь кнопки разместите вызов функции сразу с аттрибутом `num`:

```
</td><td><button onclick=`ChangeCards(${num})`>Change card</button></td>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что я поменял кавыки на " на обратный апостроф `` ` ``  (там где буква ё), чтобы заработала интерполяция `` `${}` ``

Comment: Не совсем понял, зачем Вы это делаете? У меня уже было значение ${num++} в ячейке, которое дает мне нужный результат. Дальше мне просто нужно этот результат из таблицы присвоить переменной X, чтобы я мог использовать это значение далее.

Comment: Проблем у меня с этим 2:

1. Я не понимаю, как присвоить значение конкретной ячейки таблицы переменной в моем коде.
2. Ячейка с данными и кнопка, по нажатию которой происходит передача данных из ячейки в переменную, должны находиться в одном ряду таблицы.

Comment: То есть, если я нажал на кнопку в первом ряду, в переменную Х должен передать 0, если нажал на кнопку во втором ряду Х = 1 и так далее. Я просто не знаю, через какие функции это сделать, а гугл и интеренет помочь мне в решении данной проблемы не смогли.

Comment: Я сразу понял ваше затруднение. Чтобы организовать поток данных вам нужно обустроить самую простую версию паттерна MVC «Модель-Представление-Контроллер», «Модель-Вид-Контроллер». Почитайте про него подробнее где-нибудь, вы поймёте что я вам предложил положить "модель" вовнутрь html-разметки в виде атрибута class. То есть разместить там же где размещён "вид". А контроллер в этом случае будет обработчик клика. Он будет узнавать где сделан клик, и считывать из модели соответствующий параметр. Немного сложно объясняю, но это самая распространённая архитектура, обязательно пригодится в дальнейшем.

Comment: Вы можете разместить этот `num` кстати прямо в кнопке: ```<td><button onclick="ChangeCards(num)">Change card</button></td>``` -- сразу передать num в функцию.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую озвученные варианты и почитаю озвученные советы. Надеюсь, это поможет мне решить мою проблему.

Comment: У меня не получилось прямо добавить переменную `num` в функцию (наверное, где-то чего-то не хватает), но я нашел другое решение. Я создал еще одну переменную `numb`, которую уже поместил в функцию в виде `${numb++}` и это (на мое искреннее удивление) сработало. При генерации, каждой кнопке присваивалось новое значение, которое совпадало со значением `num` в столбце "Numner". В результате, все операции начали выполняться корректно. Спасибо за подсказку. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.